# Get list of loaded libraries in C++ on Linux (at runtime)

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

How can you obtain the list of all loaded shared libraries and their memory addresses (start, end) from a running C++ program?

I'm writing a small crash reporting utility that outputs what libraries were loaded at what address ranges at the time of a crash along with other information. Here is what I'm using for Windows:

```
void GetLoadedModules(std::vector<Module> &modules) {
  HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, 0);
  if (snapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    MODULEENTRY32 module_entry;
    module_entry.dwSize = sizeof(module_entry);
    if (Module32First(snapshot, &module_entry)) {
      do {
        Module module(module_entry.szModule,
                      (uint32_t)module_entry.modBaseAddr,
                      module_entry.modBaseSize);
        modules.push_back(module);
        module_entry.dwSize = sizeof(module_entry);
      } while (Module32Next(snapshot, &module_entry));
    }
    CloseHandle(snapshot);
  }
}
```

Can you do something equivalent on Linux? Or is it best to read from something like `/proc/$pid/maps`?

**Update:**

Here is what I ended up with. As suggested by @n.m. in his/her comment I used `dl_iterate_phdr` to achieve this:

```
extern const char *__progname;

int VisitModule(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data) {
  std::vector<Module> *modules = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<Module> *>(data);

  const char *name = info->dlpi_name;
  if (modules->size() == 0) {
    // First visited entry is the main program.
    name = __progname;
  }

  uint32_t base_address = info->dlpi_addr;
  uint32_t total_size = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < info->dlpi_phnum; i++) {
    total_size += info->dlpi_phdr[i].p_memsz;
  }

  Module module(name, base_address, total_size);
  modules->push_back(module);
  return 0;
}

void GetLoadedModules(std::vector<Module> &modules) {
  modules.clear();
  dl_iterate_phdr(VisitModule, reinterpret_cast<void *>(&modules));
}
```

Comment: See `man  dl_iterate_phdr`.